# Comments starting with a straight line in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, format, styles, comments, javadoc

[image] Here is the comment style that I want to create but I don't know how.

I was looking the whole net and intellij but I can't find the solution how to create comments like this. Does anybody know how to do comments like this?

Answer (score 0):

It's a rendered view for common comments: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-code-documentation.html#toggle-rendered-view